# ASP.NET randomly caching output

Tags: asp.net, ajax, postback

I created a basic asp.net page, with a GridView and simple controls for search and paging purposes. If I click on the "next page" button, sometimes the output is exactly the same than the previous postback, sometimes is the correct output.

This behavior was found using regular and ajax postbacks. And I have used Fiddler and confirmed that is not the browser caching the output.

And I am not using any outputcache directive.

Example:
open page, click "next", it's still page 1. click "next" again, now it's page 3.

It is completely random, sometimes it works fine, sometimes don't. Does anyone know what could be causing this behavior?

ASPX Page:

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelSearch" runat="server" GroupingText="Search Result" HorizontalAlign="Left"
        Width="100%" Style="clear: both">
        <uc1:dashboard_search ID="Dashboard_search1" runat="server" OnOnNeedSubs="Dashboard_search1_OnNeedSubs" /><br />
     <asp:Button ID="btnBack" runat="server" Text="Previous page" Visible="false" 
            onclick="btnBack_Click" />&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="lblPageNumber" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp; <asp:Button ID="btnNext"
         runat="server" Text="Next Page" Visible="false" 
            onclick="btnNext_Click"/>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidPageNumber" runat="server" Value="0" />
    </asp:Panel>
```

This code is inside an UpdatePanel (but without an UpdatePanel it still occurs the same thing).

This is the code behind code:

```
public void Dashboard_search1_OnNeedSubs(object sender, SubSSDEventArgs e)
{
    e.SubSSDs = doSearch();
}

protected List<SubSSD> doSearch()
{
    // [filter code]

    int total = SubSSD.getTotalNumber();
    int page = Convert.ToInt32(hidPageNumber.Value);

    if (page == 0) 
       btnBack.Visible = false;
    else 
       btnBack.Visible = true;

    if (page + 26 >= total) 
       btnNext.Visible = false;
    else 
       btnNext.Visible = true;

    lblPageNumber.Text = "Page " + Convert.ToInt32((page / 25) + 1) + "/" + Convert.ToInt32((total / 25) + 1);

    List<SubSSD> subssds = SubSSD.search(page, page + 26);
    return subssds;
}

protected void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int page = Convert.ToInt32(hidPageNumber.Value);
    hidPageNumber.Value = Convert.ToString(page - 25);

}
protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int page = Convert.ToInt32(hidPageNumber.Value);
    hidPageNumber.Value = Convert.ToString(page + 25);

}
```

Comment: Can you post some code? where you're getting the data from and binding it to the grid might be helpful, as well as the grid definition on the page.

Answer (score 0):

To completely eliminate the browser side, I would attach a random url parameter. I'll note that most of the major javascript libraries do this transparently with their ajax features.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you should either put some logging in place or a lot of breakpoints to identify exactly which methods are being called in which order.

I suspect that the grid binding is happening out of order of your next page code.

Comment: Could be, but would this order change randomly (sometimes it works)?

Comment: I just put a lot of breakpoints and discovered that, when it doesn't work, the OnPreRender event of the user control (Dashboard_search) is never called, so its event (Dashboard_search1_OnNeedSubs) is never triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Guys, i found out why it was having such strange behavior, there was a OutputCache directive in the user control, for caching the content for 5 seconds.